# What file formats do oscilloscopes export?

Tags: oscilloscope, storage

Many digital storage oscilloscopes can export data for further analysis.

What kind of file formats do oscilloscopes use to export capture data over USB, Ethernet, or on a USB stick?  Which oscilloscopes produce which formats?

Comment: Take a look at sigrok, open source software for working with lots of logic analysers http://sigrok.org

Comment: @m.Alin - Sorry for the confusion - We've discussed it, and it's been reopened as a CW question so that we can support a list of answers.  Also, I've removed the "Additionally, what software is available to process the data (waveforms) from the oscilloscope?" question, that's a separate issue and deserves its own question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The scopes I've worked with could save **screenshots as bitmaps** (BMP or PNG), and a few formats of **numerical data**, among which there was always **CSV** (Comma-Separated Values), which can be used to import in MatLab, Excel, or any program you write that can handle text files (Edlin anyone? :-)).
Other formats are mostly **proprietary**, I don't think there's a universal **XML** format for scope data as yet.

Comment: I hope there never is a universal XML format, XML is massively bloated in both size and parsing time, terrible for numerical data really.

Comment: @Mark - XML is bloated, but what do you care, at 5 cent per GB? Besides, nobody can stop you to use base-64 encoded blocks. XML is the way most cross-application data exchange is done.

Comment: It actually is an issue if your using a scope with a slow connection, I've yet to see one with GB network link.  Its always USB (often 1.1), USB Thumb Drive (slow), or 10/100 Ethernet.  All of which are more of a pain to use when the data size is increase by a factor of 10.  Secondly the parse time is the truly annoying issue for large data-sets.  All these reason are, incidently, why i never use XML in micro-controller applications but rather a binary wire format, usually google's protocol buffers.